# The namespace RDotNet could not be found

Tags: c#, r

I'm trying to use R with C#. I'm using Unity and MonoDevelop on the C# side and I've R version 3.2.1. I've tried my best to follow instructions here: http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/getting_started/

But I'm stuck. Here's what I've done

- download nuget.exe, put it in a folder already in PATH.
- open CMD.exe
- run `nuget install R.NET.Community`

If I try to reinstall R.NET.Community with the same command above, I got the message that it is already installed (which is good I guess).

My question : what now? I tried to run the RDotNet namespace, but it's not recognized. Obviously I need to set up something else, but I do not know where and what. Any lead would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using visual studio?

Comment: @acostela: "I'm using Unity and MonoDevelop"

Comment: I mean for the IDE. If you are using something like Visual Studio it's easy to add the reference to your project. The problem is that you just downloaded the package but you must reference it in order to use the namespace

Comment: Just installed Visual Studio, I will try and see if it helps me getting my namespace :-)

Comment: @acostela: Yes, I know you mean for the IDE - but MonoDevelop *is* an IDE...

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't expect just running the nuget install to add a reference into your project - the nuget installer is basically just downloading the package for you.

You *could* manually add a reference in your project to the relevant assembly file (.dll) that has been downloaded. However, it would be better to use a package manager within MonoDevelop. If you're using MonoDevelop 3.x or 4.5, you should use the [NuGet MonoDevelop add-in](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin) and use that to manage the NuGet packages for your project. MonoDevelop 5.x has a NuGet package manager built in, apparently.

Comment: I've got MonoDevelop 4.0.1. I followed instructions here https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin to get nutget within MonoDevelop. Then in Project>Manage NuGet Packages, I performed a search for R.NET.Community, found it, tried to add it, now I run into this error: Could not install package 'DynamicInterop 0.7.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Comment: @Thomas: Well that's a problem in terms of your platform requirements, I'm afraid... you might want to try older versions of R.NET, assuming you can't use a more recent version of .NET. (I don't *think* any versions of Unity target .NET 4 unfortunately.)

Comment: What If I (re)install MonoDevelop to get the most up to date version of it? I've just checked, I've also .NET 4.5 installed. Will all this be incompatible with Unity do you think? In any case, thanks for your answer, it was already quite helpful :-)

Comment: @Thomas: No, reinstalling MonoDevelop won't help if Unity is stuck with .NET 3.5, which I believe it is.

Comment: I tried Xamarin and I got the same issue. I performed some research and it indeed comes down to this: Unity works with .NET 3.5. The package DynamicInterop 0.7.4 does not. That's it. I've found online that the oldest version of DynamicInterop is 0.7.0. I don't know if this is compatible with .NET 3.5 or even how to install this old version.

Comment: @Thomas: Having just tried installing it myself, no, it doesn't - it targets .NET 4.

Comment: All right, I guess I will have to try using R by letting my C# code dumping raw data on the hard disk and let R loading it up. Not pretty, but that should work. Dear Jon, thanks a lot for your time, I appreciate it :-)

Comment: @Thomas: Looking at other versions of the R.Community.NET package, version 1.5.16 doesn't depend on DynamicInterop - but it's *also* .NET 4+.

Comment: I'm out of luck today it seems :-)